# How do you get the parent reference in firebase using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have this code in javascript that sorts through all blog posts, ordered by timestamp and gets the corresponding information. What I don't know how to do however is get the parent reference.

[image]

So as you can see what I am trying to get is the unique key or parent reference associated with the project data I receive with this code:-

```
let endpoint = "/blog_group/blogs/";
firebase.database().ref(endpoint)
.orderByChild('timestamp')
.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  this.data = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    this.data.push(child.val());
  }.bind(this));
  timestamp = data.map(function(val) { return new Date(val.timestamp).toString(); });
  title = data.map(function(val) { return val.title; });
  body = data.map(function(val) { return val.body; });
console.log(timestamp,title,body);
});
```

> ["Thu Feb 08 2018 15:57:12 GMT-0500 (EST)"] ["Why is coffee good for you?"] ["This would be the body of the blog..."]

The code above produces what you see highlighted in the console so I am successfully retrieving the data I just need to be able to retrieve the parent reference `L4rCHNlkxdX4s2WckAg`. If you know how I can incorporate this into my code it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the string `"L4r..."` what you want to get? If so, you can access it using `snapshot.key`. If you really do want the parent reference and not the key, then `snapshot.ref.parent` will do that for you.

Comment: Yeah, I want the string `"L4r..."`, where do I insert snapshot.key? And is that all I need?

Comment: In your case, that would be the key of the child snapshot. So you might consider just adding it as a field to the data objects you're using. EG: `this.data.push({id: child.key, ...snap.val()})` inside your `.forEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the key:-

```
var ids = [];
let endpoint = "/blog_group/blogs/";
firebase.database().ref(endpoint).orderByChild('timestamp').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    this.data = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        ids.push(child.key); 
        this.data.push(child.val());
    }.bind(this));
    timestamp = data.map(function(val) {
        return new
        Date(val.timestamp).toString();
    });
    title = data.map(function(val) {
        return val.title;
    });
    body = data.map(function(val) {
        return val.body;
    });
    console.log(timestamp, title, body, ids);
});
```

`var ids=child.key`
add this line under the forEach to be able to retrieve the key which is the id.

Comment: So will ids hold all the keys?

Comment: @AnthonySette yes

Comment: When I call ids right below the definition it alerts each key, but I can't call the ids where you see my `console.log("timestamp");`. It says undefined, any way to call it down there?

Comment: Global works!! Can't believe I missed that, thanks. It only alerts the final key though, do I push them to an array or something?

Comment: I just edited the answer so that it is an array holding all the keys. Waiting for peer review before I accept your answer!

Comment: You don't need `ids` in the global scope, nor any reference to `this`.  It can even be `const` at the top of the function body.  Storing things in the global scope, as a general practice, is not a best practice, and potentially costs more money over time.

Comment: @DougStevenson What do you mean by this, I guess you could say I am a noob and I would love to know more!